What does the straight line of a 3 Plane sheaf mean geometrically with the variables that it is represented by?
(Can't find a straight answer, doing A level further maths) Here's my full question:
3 Planes, s̶h̶e̶a̶f̶  pencil going through
The planes are each represented by a matrix
(x,y,z)
EDITED Example:

(1) 3x - y - 6z = 1
(2) 1x + 3y + 3z = 2
(3) -3x -y + 3z = -1

(1) + 2 • (2): 5x + 5y = 5 (4)
(2)-(3): 4x + 4y = 4 (5)
In this case we get a linear multiple of the other, meaning it is consistent, meaning the planes meet along a line.
It has 2 variables and since it is a line, it is 2 dimensional.
However, how is it also represented in a 3 Dimensional space?
If the matrix equations are not the normal of the planes, what do they mean?
EDIT: attached images from textbook:
Textbook Section
Full pages of textbook

well, your link shows just three planes with a common line. I don't know why planes would be represented by a "matrix."   The picture would not usually be called a "sheaf"  in mathematics, although that may be a colloquial usage. Anyway, I can't make any sense of this.

@WillJagy When I was doing my A-Levels, this configuration of planes was called a sheaf in the textbook, so I have seen this usage before, but I also do not know how common it is to call it this.

There are things missing. If the three planes pass through the origin, each can be specified by a perpendicular vector.  If those three vectors have a common perpendicular vector  $v,$   the intersection line of the planes is all multiples of $v,$    as a parametrization  $t v$   for all real $t.$   This is, of course, not what usually happens. Given three planes though the origin,   the three normal vectors are usually linearly independent:  the 3 by 3 matrix with those vectors as rows  is  nonsingular, nonzero determinant

I guess you should paste in images from your textbook.

@WillJagy Hi, thanks for helping, I've edited the post, adding the exact info from the textbook.

what is the title of the book?  Authors?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@WillJagy Pearson Edexcel AS and A level Further Mathematics, Core Pure Mathematics, Book1/AS: Authors: Greg Attwood, Jack Barraclough, Ian Bettison, Lee Cope, Charles Garnet Cox, Daniel Goldberg, Alistair MacPherson, Brown Moran, Su Nicholson, Laurence Pateman, Joe Petran, Keith Pledger, Harry Smith, Geoff Staley, Dave Wilkins. Page 116, Solving systems of equations using matrices.

found a preview  but not page 116  https://www.pearson.com/content/dam/one-dot-com/one-dot-com/international-schools/pdfs/secondary-curriculum/international-a-levels/mathematics/International-A-Level-Mathematics-Further-Pure-Mathematics-1-Student-Book-sample.pdf

This is not mathematicians’ language. We refer to this as a pencil of planes (having a common line).

Hi, I've added the question with examples and attached the whole section of the textbook.
